# RecyclerView duplicating certain UI elements

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a dynamic view inside of a RecyclerView and I'm having issues with certain controls being duplicated.

Here is my RecyclerView.ViewHolder

```
class CardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ICard card;
    private TextView cost;
    private ImageView quickAction;
    private TextView range;
    private TextView life;
    private TextView defense;
    private TextView spellName;
    private ImageView addCard;
    private TextView maximumCards;
    private ImageView removeCard;
    private ImageView cardImage;
    private LinearLayout cardImageRow;
    private LinearLayout traitsRow;
    private TextView effects;
    private LinearLayout attackColumn;


    public CardHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cost = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_cost);
        quickAction = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.quickAction);
        range = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.range);
        life = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.life);
        defense = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.defense);
        spellName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spellName);
        addCard = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.addCard);
        addCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        maximumCards = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.maximumCards);
        removeCard = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeCard);
        removeCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        cardImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
        cardImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        cardImageRow = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImageRow);
        traitsRow = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.traitsRow);
        effects = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.effects);
        attackColumn = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attackColumn);
    }

    public void setCard(Card card){
        this.card = card;

        cost.setText(card.getCost() + "");
        quickAction.setImageResource(card.isQuickAction() ? R.drawable.quickaction : R.drawable.fullaction);
        range.setText(card.getMinRange() + "-" + card.getMaxRange());
        spellName.setText(card.getSpellName());
        cardImage.setImageResource(card.getCardImageResourceId());
        effects.setText(card.getEffect());

        if(card instanceof AttackCard){
            AttackCard c = (AttackCard)card;
            handleAttack(c.getAttack());
        }


        if(card.getTrait() != null){
            boolean isFirst = true;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < card.getTrait().getAll().size(); i++){
                if(isFirst){
                    builder.append(card.getTrait().get(i).getType().toString());
                    isFirst = false;
                }
                else{
                    builder.append(" \u2022 ");
                    builder.append(card.getTrait().get(i).getType().toString());
                }
            }

            TextView t = new TextView(getActivity());
            t.setText(builder.toString());
            t.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
            t.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            traitsRow.addView(t);


        }
    }
    private void handleAttack(ICardProperty<IAttack> attack){
        if(attack == null){
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < attack.getAll().size(); i++) {

            IAttack a = attack.get(i);

            //Layout for entire Attack
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            //layout.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            //Attack name
            TextView attackName = new TextView(getActivity());
            attackName.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            attackName.setText(a.getName());
            attackName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            attackName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            attackName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
            layout.addView(attackName);


            //Quick action or Full action
            ImageView quickAction = new ImageView(getActivity());
            quickAction.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(R.dimen.card_header_width,R.dimen.card_header_height);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,attackName.getId());
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            quickAction.setLayoutParams(lp);
            quickAction.setImageResource(a.isQuickAction() ? R.drawable.quickaction : R.drawable.fullaction);
            layout.addView(quickAction);

            //Attack type (Melee or Ranged)
            TextView attackType = new TextView(getActivity());
            attackType.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            attackType.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(R.dimen.attack_width,R.dimen.attack_height);
            p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,quickAction.getId());
            p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,attackName.getId());
            p1.setMargins(2,0,2,0);

            if(a.getAttackType() == IAttack.AttackType.Melee){
                attackType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.melee);
            }
            else if(a.getAttackType() == IAttack.AttackType.Ranged){
                attackType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.range);
                attackType.setText(a.getMinRange() + "-" + a.getMaxRange());
                attackType.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                attackType.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                attackType.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            }

            layout.addView(attackType);
            attackColumn.addView(layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ICard> cards;

    public CardAdapter(ArrayList<ICard> cards){
        super();
        this.cards = cards;
    }
    @Override
    public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_card_row, parent, false);
        return new CardHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardHolder holder, int position) {
        ICard card = cards.get(position);
        holder.setCard((Card)card);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }
}
```

In the setCard method I'm interrogating the Card object and adding various UI elements accordingly. It seems to work fine for a short period of time but it quickly becomes apparent that UI elements that are dynamically added are duplicating themselves. As you scroll up and down there will be more and more of them.

Am I doing something wrong by dynamically adding UI code in the onBindViewHolder of the adapter? If so what would be the correct way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Even I have the same problem, Did you got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove all views from your parent on   onBindViewHolder().